# Integrating Wicked, Devise and Omniauth-Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth, wicked-gem

I am developing an application using these three gem I wrote in the title of this post. I set up devise with the confirmable module(?), so when a user creates an account with its email/password, it receives a confirmation email. If the user sign up with facebook (using omniauth-facebook gem) devise skips the confirmation step.

In user.rb

```
    "Of course the :confirmable is active in the model"
    ...

    # Omniauth-facebook
    def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth)
      where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
        user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
        user.skip_confirmation!
        # user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
      end
    end

    ...
```

The thing comes when I added the wicked gem for the wizard. I configured the routes file

in routes.rb

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks =>  "users/omniauth_callbacks",
          :registrations => "registrations" }

  root 'home#index'

  # Registration wizard routes
  resources :after_register
end
```

The I created a registration_controller to override the devise registration methods

```
    class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

      def create
        super
      end

    protected

     def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
       puts "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< SIGN IN"
       after_register_path(:import_contacts)
     end

     def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
       puts "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< SIGN UP ACTIVE"
     after_register_path(:import_contacts)
   end

   def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    puts "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< SIGN IN INACTIVE"
    after_register_path(:import_contacts)
   end
 end
```

And then, I created a new controller to handle the steps of the wizard with wicked.

```
   class AfterRegisterController < ApplicationController
     include Wicked::Wizard
     before_filter :authenticate_user!

     steps :import_contacts, :select_agents, :wish_form

     def show
       @user = current_user
       render_wizard
     end

     def update
       @user = current_user
       @user.attributes = params[:user]
       render_wizard @user
     end

   end
```

When I create a user rith email/password, the wizard comes and everything works fine, but when I try to sign up with facebook, the wizars never comes.

Any hint???

Thank you!!

Comment: Can you tell me how did you write your view files using render_wizard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything is configured in the usual way (and what I can see looks pretty standard), then signing in using Facebook won't go via the `RegistrationsController` at all.  It will go via the `OmniauthCallbacks` controller which you haven't posted the code for.  It depends what you do in there when they log in via Facebook.  I assume that you have a `facebook()` method which calls `User.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth)`.  Are you then just signing them in rather than going to the `RegistrationsController`?  If so, then the `RegistrationsController` won't be touched, so its overridden `after_sign_in_path_for` won't have any effect.

If you want to have your overridden `after_sign_in_path_for` take effect throughout your app, you can define it in your `ApplicationController`.  If you only want it to take effect in your `OmniauthCallbacksController`, you could define it there.  In either case, they'll be hitting it every time they log in using Facebook (and if you put it in the `ApplicationController`, every time anyone logs in using any method), so you'd need to keep track of the fact that they have already been through the wizard, assuming you want to make sure that it only happens the first time they sign in.  If you're using the devise :trackable module, perhaps checking the user.sign_in_count would be appropriate, or perhaps you have some other way to easily check if they have been through the wizard already.

UPDATE FOR COMMENT QUESTIONS:

Your first question: "Assuming I put the after_sign_in_path_fot in ApplicationController, I should remove the after_inactive_sign_up_path_for method in RegistrationsController, right?"  It depends on what behaviour you want. With the `RegistrationsController` as in your question it will go to the wizard after they've signed up and before they've confirmed their email (because of `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` which will be called in this case).  When they confirm and sign in, the `after_sign_in_path_for` in `ApplicationController` will send them to the wizard again. So yes, remove inactive from `RegistrationsController` if you just want wizard after sign in.  Then probably `after_sign_up_path_for(resource)` in `RegistrationsController` is unnecessary because the default implementation in devise just calls `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` which you will have in your `ApplicationController`.  Anyway, `after_sign_up_path_for()` won't be called if you always require confirmation because of the logic in the default implementation of `RegistrationsController.create()` - requiring confirmation will result in `resource.active_for_authentication?` returning false which causes `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)` to be called.

For the question in your second comment, you said "If I remove the after_sign_in_path_for in ApplicationController" - I assume you meant `RegistrationsController`?  If that's right, then yes, there would be no methods needed in your overridden version of `RegistrationsController` (if that's the whole controller you pasted in your question) because your `create()` just calls `super`, the `after_sign_in_path_for` would be in `ApplicationController` and you probably don't want either of the `after_(inactive)_sign_up_path_for` methods as discussed above.  So yes, there would be no need for your `RegistrationsController`.  You could remove it completely and remove the `:registrations => "registrations"` in routes.rb - the devise implementation of `RegistrationsController` will then be used again.

Then you say "just override the methods of RegistrationsController in ApplicationController?".  The only method you will have left from your `RegistrationsController` is the `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` in `ApplicationController`, so I don't think there will be any other methods from your `RegistrationsController` that you need in `ApplicationController`.   Let me know if I've missed one of your requirements or made an incorrect assumption.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yes, I figured it out that the RegistrationsController has nothing to do with the facebook login. I have found a solution, but it looks more dirty than yours (yours is absolutely better).

I used a new field in the user model as a flag (it does exactly the same thing as sign_up_count) and then in the facebook method in OmniauthCallbacks I call @user.update_attribute(:flag, true).

Assuming I put the after_sign_in_path_fot in ApplicationController, I should remove the after_inactive_sign_up_path_for method in RegistrationsController, right? thanks!

Comment: Another question. If I remove the after_sign_in_path_for in ApplicationController it won't have any methods inside. So what happens with the :registrations => "registrations" in routes.rb? Do I have to remove that too and just override the methods of RegistrationsController in ApplicationController?

Thanks again!

Comment: Edited answer to include answers to your questions.  Sorry it's a bit long now!

Comment: Wow!! what a good and clear answer, my friend!! It really helped me. Thanks!